# Partial Derivative in FeynCalc

Tags: packages, algorithm, feyncalc

I try to compute some loop diagram in *Mathematica* with `FeynCalc` package.
In the nominator, I have a huge trace and it shows the right solution but in the next step I need to find the solution of a partial derivative such as simply

```
FieldDerivative[FV[p,μ].DiracMatrix[ν],{FV[p,ν]}]
```

and output is

$\partial_{p^{\nu}}(p^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}$

But absolutely I expect

$\gamma^{\mu}$

So do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance...

Note: I used "Contract" function but it doesn't work...

Comment: I am not a user of it but isn't a field derivative just an $x$-derivative which simply adds a new factor of a momentum $p\sim -i\partial$ on top of the existing one?

Comment: Thank you for your interest...  as you can see it is written as $\partial_{p^{\nu}}$ and even if we write x instead of p, it behaves similarly...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a software, not physics.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I flagged it for migration in Mathematica.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `?FieldDerivative` you see that it contains following text

> NOTICE: FieldDerivative is defined only for objects with head \
>   QuantumField[...]. If the space-time derivative of other objects is \
>   wanted, the corresponding rule must be specified.

I.e. `FieldDerivative` is used for deriving Feynman rules, but not for differentiating Lorentz tensors. What you need is `FourDivergence` and this is the code for what you are trying to do:

```
FourDivergence[FV[p, mu] GA[nu], FV[p, nu]]
```

which returns what you expect.

P.S. There is a dedicated [mailing list](http://www.feyncalc.org/forum/) for questions related to FeynCalc.